# Doesn't show scroll in JScrollPane with JTable after Upgrade Java 7 to Java 8

Tags: java, swing, java-8, jtable, jscrollpane

I've to upgrade project to Java 8. After running my application, scroll from JScrollPane doesn't show. Same piece of code works in Java 7 and everything is ok.

```
public static void main(String[] a){
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    contentPane.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(contentPane, javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JPanel aggregates = new JPanel("Aggregates", new Insets(40, 0, 0, 0));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_aggregates = new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, 1, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10), 0, 0);
    gbl_panel.setConstraints(aggregates, gbc_aggregates);

    GridBagLayout gbl_agregats = new GridBagLayout();   
    addParametersLayout(gbl_agregats, new int[]{0,0,0}, new int[]{0, 0},new double[]{ 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE}, new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE} );
    aggregates.setLayout(gbl_agregats);

    JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel(null));
    table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850, Const.rowHeight));

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(850, 10 *Const.rowHeight));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane= new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 3, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, 1, new Insets(5, 5, 20, 5), 0, 0);
    gbl_agregats.setConstraints(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);
    aggregates.add(scrollPane);

    JPanel main_panel = new JPanel();
    main_panel.add(aggregates); 

    JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(main_panel);
    scrPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
    scrPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    scrPane.getInsets().set(0, 0, 0, 0);
    contentPane.add(scrPane);
    setContentPane(contentPane);    
}

public static void addParametersLayout(GridBagLayout gbl,
int[] columnWidths, int[] rowHeights, double[] columnWeights,
double[] rowWeights) {
    gbl.columnWidths = columnWidths;
    gbl.rowHeights = rowHeights;
    gbl.columnWeights = columnWeights;
    gbl.rowWeights = rowWeights;
}
```

**Question: What was changed in Java 8 ? Why same scroll looks ok in older Java version ?**

**Edited:**

Maybe i'm not too specific.
When i compile my project i see something like that (just bar):

[image]

I can scroll my table because it's working, but it's invisible (i see just a bar).

Comment: *"table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850, Const.rowHeight));*" would be a questionable start

Comment: Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: May be the L&F used changed. Nimbus is intrusive enough to trigger such changes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
          import java.awt.Color;
          import java.awt.Dimension;
          import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
          import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
          import java.awt.Insets;
          import java.awt.LayoutManager;
          import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
          import javax.swing.JPanel;
          import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
          import javax.swing.JTab
          import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;



          public class source8 {




          public static void main(String[] a){
          JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
          contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
          contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
          contentPane.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(contentPane,  

          javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

          JPanel aggregates = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new Insets(40, 0,0,
          0));
          GridBagConstraints gbc_aggregates = new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 
          1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, 1, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 
          10), 0, 0);
          GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();    

          gbl_panel.setConstraints(aggregates, gbc_aggregates);

          GridBagLayout gbl_agregats = new GridBagLayout();   
          addParametersLayout(gbl_agregats, new int[]{0,0,0}, new int[]{0, 
          0},new double[]{ 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE}, new double[]{0.0,
          Double.MIN_VALUE} );
          aggregates.setLayout(gbl_agregats);

          JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel(null));
          table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850, Const.rowHeight));

          JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
          table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(850, 10 
          *Const.rowHeight));
          GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane= new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 3,
          1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, 1, new Insets(5, 5, 20, 5),
          0, 0);
          gbl_agregats.setConstraints(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);
          aggregates.add(scrollPane);

          JPanel main_panel = new JPanel();
          main_panel.add(aggregates); 

          JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(main_panel);
          scrPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
          scrPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
          scrPane.getInsets().set(0, 0, 0, 0);
          contentPane.add(scrPane);
          setContentPane(contentPane);    
          }

          public static void addParametersLayout(GridBagLayout gbl,
          int[] columnWidths, int[] rowHeights, double[] columnWeights,
          double[] rowWeights) {
          gbl.columnWidths = columnWidths;
          gbl.rowHeights = rowHeights;
          gbl.columnWeights = columnWeights;
          gbl.rowWeights = rowWeights;
          } 

          private static void setContentPane(JPanel contentPane) {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");                
          //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
          }
           }
```

some change in code hope it works for you §§thanks

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem. I added default ScrollBar size for my LookAndFeel and it works.

```
UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getDefaults();
defaults.put("ScrollBar.minimumThumbSize", new Dimension(30, 30));
```